# JavaScript -- encode object with special characters

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an ExtJS grid with an export functionality for which the selected row/record object is submitted. The issue is there is one column that sometimes has special chars, in particular `the less than char <`and because of this the encoded string is unexpectedly terminated.

Here is my code for submitting the download:

```
Ext.dom.Query.selectNode("iframe[name=myiframe]").src = myDownloadUrl +"?records=" + Ext.encode(records);
```

Incomplete encoded records object after submitting download when < char is present:

```
records:[{"id":1141,"view_name":"freemarker","view_value":"<
```

So the string gets terminated at the very first < char.

In rows where there is no < char the whole record object is submitted and everything works fine.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try urlEncoding *records* with `Ext.Object.toQueryString(records)`

Example from [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Object.html#method-toQueryString):

```
Ext.Object.toQueryString({foo: 1, bar: 2}); // returns "foo=1&bar=2"
Ext.Object.toQueryString({foo: null, bar: 2}); // returns "foo=&bar=2"
Ext.Object.toQueryString({'some price': '$300'}); // returns "some%20price=%24300"
Ext.Object.toQueryString({date: new Date(2011, 0, 1)}); // returns "date=%222011-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%22"
Ext.Object.toQueryString({colors: ['red', 'green', 'blue']}); // returns "colors=red&colors=green&colors=blue"
```

If you are encoding an array of objects you can:

```
Ext.Object.toQueryString({data:records},true)
```

and you will have the data encoded like `data[0][id]=1141,data[0][view_name]=freemarker,data[1][id]=232,data[1][view_name]=abc,etc...`

Comment: in this case it submits the whole record but all the keys like "id", "view_name", "view_value" etc become 0. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you are encoding an array. Updated answer

Comment: thanks, this could work but will require some backend changes. Going to keep this question open to see if anyone has a better solution